# use PHP in Adobe Flash Builder 4 on localhost

Tags: php, apache-flex, localhost, flashbuilder4

I would like to use my localhost database and some PHP in my Flex projects (using Flash Builder 4). I've searched on the web for some good tutorials, but couldn't find one. The only decent I found was [this one](http://corlan.org/2009/06/12/working-in-flash-builder-4-with-flex-and-php/), but I ran into a problem when trying to install ZendFrameWork.

Does anyone knows a good place to start learning using PHP into Adobe Flas Builder 4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little detour, I came to [this](http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/building-a-database-based-app-using-flex-and-php-with-flash-builder-4/). And this was my solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to define what you want each player to do.  Flash Builder is probably going to be on the client side.  PHP, although it can do client side work, is going to be on the server side, assuming "normal" implementation.

So what do you want PHP to do.  Again, I am going to assume the "normal" and you want PHP to serve up data.  One of the easiest ways to integrate that data into Flash Builder is via JSON so this article handles the PHP side
http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Creating_JSON_Data_in_PHP
and this article handles the Flash Builder side
http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2009/06/05/consuming-json-using-data-centric-development-feature-dcd-in-flash-builder-4/

There are other ways to pass data (XML, say), but until you decide what it is that you are trying to do, exactly, the above should get you started.

Comment: I took a quick look to the documents and they seems fine to help me out. What I'm trying to do is this: we are building a mobile app. Both in JQueryMobile and Flex. We build the whole database en PHP scripts for the mobile variant, but now we want to do the same for Flex (AIR). So we need to talk to our database and PHP query's to get the data out of de database. Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

I use AMFPHP as server side framework and PHPEd as ide for php :)

Answer (score 0):

WebORB all the way! It's free for PHP
http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-php/overview.html

There are several tutorials both articles and video's on that page for setting it up, using it, and having it auto-generate a lot of the nuts and bolts as3 code for you.